# Excel SUMIFS with Ranges as Criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm having some issues getting SUMIFS to do what I want (maybe because it cannot). Here's exactly what I'm trying to setup:

- Sheet with denormalized data (server, files by extensions, counts, sizes)
- Sheet with rows of strings (server names)
- Sheet with rows of string + formula

Basically I'm trying to look at how the data on my various data servers is bucketed. So I have a list of extensions that I care about (let's say .docx, .xlsx, and .pptx) and a list of servers I care about (let's say serv_a, serv_b, and serv_c). Given the massive worksheet I have with all the data from all the servers and all the files I need to get the count of files on the server which have extensions that I care about.

Here's the formula I'm using now (it is not working)

```
  =SUMIFS(data!$C:$C, data!$A:$A, A2, data!$B:$B, filter!$A:$A)
```

Where data!$C is the count of a extension on a server, data!$A is the server name, A2 is server name I want to filter on, and filter!$A is the list of extensions I want to filter on.

I do think it's the LIST of extensions to filter by which is breaking things. Given a single value (.docx) I can count 143,567 files on a given server, but the query returns 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter a range of cell as criteria, you'll have to enter it as [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx) (see link).
You do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Your formula should then look like below:

`{=SUMIFS(data!$C:$C, data!$A:$A, A2, data!$B:$B, filter!$A:$A)}`

That will then return an array of values which are the `SUMIFS` result of each criteria.
To return it into a single value, sum it up using `SUM` which accepts array parameter.
Final formula should look like below, again entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. HTH.

`{=SUM(SUMIFS(data!$C:$C, data!$A:$A, A2, data!$B:$B, filter!$A:$A))}`

**Bonus:** Credits to [barry houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini)

This non-array formula works the same way:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(data!$C:$C, data!$A:$A, A2, data!$B:$B, filter!$A:$A))`

Comment: I never would have guess that I needed to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead of just Enter. You're my hero!

Comment: You can avoid CSE if you use SUMPRODUCT in place of SUM

Comment: The =SUMPRODUCT(...) version seems to hang Excel - anyone else encounter this issue before? CPU usage spikes then eventually the OS kills the app.

Comment: @focuspark I don't encounter that. And it recalculates faster than the array formula when dealing with huge date sets.

Comment: @L42 thanks - I think you just confirmed it is time to reinstall my  copy of Office. aside: I've redone the query in T-SQL and it only takes 2.5 sec to complete.